# Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:5:1

Tags: json, sublimetext2

Every time I open up Sublime Text 2 I receive the following error:


Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:5:1


I have examined the contents of the [Settings-Default folder](https://gist.github.com/zfine416/e86a95e46b9cfdc18fb2) and cant find anything wrong. I have included a gist above. Any ideas what might be causing the error. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I added a comment in my Key Bindings - User folder that was throwing the error.